# 'NETCore.App', version '1.0.0-rc2-3002702' was not found

Tags: asp.net

I have s default ASP.NET Core project added in Visual Studio. I did nothing just published the project and deployed it on Windows Server 2012 RC2.
I have installed DotNetCore

I configured IIS but when I run the project I'll get an error.

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.0-rc2-3002702' was not found.

  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed     at:
      C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App

  - The following versions are installed:       1.0.0
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.0-rc2-3002702'.
```

Please help

Comment: Are you sure you installed the [.NET Core SDK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=809122) on the server machine?

Comment: DotNetCore.1.0.0-WindowsHosting is currently installed on the server. I've read the configuration / installation guide on this page https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle

Comment: Now I have installed the NET Core SDK but with the same result. In the eventlog I found this message:

    Failed to start process with commandline '"dotnet" .\Website.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005'.

Comment: It sounds like you have .NET Core 1.0 (RTM) installed on the server, but RC2 installed on your development machine. What's the output of `dotnet --version` on both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue ,and i deal it just change 1.0.1 to 1.0.0 in runtimeconfig.json

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that there are tools in your dependencies and in the tools sections of your project.json file that may have different versions. For example, :

```
  "tools": {
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "imports": ...
  ]
}
```

and

```
  "dependencies": {
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "type": "build",
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  ...
}
```

will cause the error you are seeing because the versions do not agree.

Comment: Scott Hanselman describes this problem detailed here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMysteryOfDotnetWatchAndMicrosoftNETCoreAppVersion110preview100110000WasNotFound.aspx